# In a scene from "Game of Hunting", people in handcuffs in a courtroom are wearing clothes marked "北看": is this correct and what does it mean?

Tags: translation, word

[image: "Game of Hunting" screenshot showing four individuals in Chinese-style handcuffs, who are wearing identical blue-and-red (or blue-and-orange) clothing. Three of those characters have 北看 marked on their clothes in white. Three police officers are visible, standing behind them.]

There are two characters written on the orange jackets (?) they are wearing. It seems like it says "北看" but I can't seem to find anything related to that meaning. If it's not "看", I hope someone can tell me what it is, and why is it even there on the jacket.  They are in court, by the way.

Comment: https://books.google.com.tw/books?isbn=1630326127 北京市公安局第一看守所，簡稱"北看" ---- but here it seems that they're talking about 北海 and not 北京.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is short for "北x市xx看守所". The TV play is based on the city of Beihai(北海市) which belongs to Guangxi province(广西省), so 北 means 北海, 看 means 看守所. The typical name should be 北海市看守所. Actually, 北海 has at least two 看守所s. One is 北海第一看守所, the other is 北海第二看守所. If 北看 means 北海市第一看守所, then the other one should be short as 北二看.